# Putting numbers into words

Tags: ruby, numbers-to-words

I have some embarrassingly long code which puts into words any number up into the trillions. As a newbie, and understanding that shorter, non-repetitive code is best, I am looking for suggestions on how to reduce this code to a respectable quantity. I realize that there is a lot of repetition in it. However, depending on the number being evaluated, the math looks a little different with each rep, so I am not sure if I can reduce that. I have tried rewriting it solely as an if/else (without the recursion) but it quickly becomes just as bad if not worse.

```
class :: Fixnum 

  def in_words(number)

    if number < 0  # No negative numbers.
      return 'Please enter a number that isn\'t negative.'
    end

    if number == 0
      return 'zero'
    end


  numString = ''  # This is the string we will return.

  onesPlace = ['one',     'two',       'three',    'four',     'five',
               'six',     'seven',     'eight',    'nine']
  tensPlace = ['ten',     'twenty',    'thirty',   'forty',    'fifty',
               'sixty',   'seventy',   'eighty',   'ninety']
  teenagers = ['eleven',  'twelve',    'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen',
               'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']

    #-----------------------------------------trillions

  left = number 
  write = left/1000000000000
  left = left - (write*1000000000000)

    if number > 999999999999

      if write < 10 #1,00 - 9,000
        millions  = onesPlace[write - 1]
        numString = numString + millions + ' trillion'
      end 

      if (write > 9) && (write < 20) #10,000 - 19,000
        if write == 10 
          millions = tensPlace[write - 10]
          numString = numString + millions + ' trillion'
        else  
          millions = teenagers[write - 11] #11 because the length of teenagers is only 9 so 15-11 = 4 and 'thirteen' is in 
          numString = numString + millions + ' trillion'
        end
      end

      if (write > 19) && (write < 1000) #here i have to use recursion to get the first two/three digets --> 19,000,000 - 999,000,000
        millions = in_words(write)
        numString = numString + millions + ' trillion'
      end

      if left > 0
        numString = numString + ' '
      end

    #-----------------------------------------billions
  #left = number 
  write = left/1000000000
  left = left - (write*1000000000)

    if number > 999999999

      if write < 10 #1,00 - 9,000
        millions  = onesPlace[write - 1]
        numString = numString + millions + ' billion'
      end 

      if (write > 9) && (write < 20) #10,000 - 19,000
        if write == 10 
          millions = tensPlace[write - 10]
          numString = numString + millions + ' billion'
        else  
          millions = teenagers[write - 11] #11 because the length of teenagers is only 9 so 15-11 = 4 and 'thirteen' is in 
          numString = numString + millions + ' billion'
        end
      end

      if (write > 19) && (write < 1000) #here i have to use recursion to get the first two/three digets --> 19,000,000 - 999,000,000
        millions = in_words(write)
        numString = numString + millions + ' billion'
      end

      if left > 0
        numString = numString + ' '
      end

 # ----------------------------------------millions
  write = left/1000000
  left = left - (write*1000000)

    if number > 999999

      if write < 10 #1,00 - 9,000
        millions  = onesPlace[write - 1]
        numString = numString + millions + ' million'
      end 

      if (write > 9) && (write < 20) #10,000 - 19,000
        if write == 10 
          millions = tensPlace[write - 10]
          numString = numString + millions + ' million'
        else  
          millions = teenagers[write - 11] #11 because the length of teenagers is only 9 so 15-11 = 4 and 'thirteen' is in 
          numString = numString + millions + ' million'
        end
      end

      if (write > 19) && (write < 1000) #here i have to use recursion to get the first two/three digets --> 19,000,000 - 999,000,000
        millions = in_words(write)
        numString = numString + millions + ' million'
      end

      if left > 0
        numString = numString + ' '
      end

 #-----------------------------------------thousands 
  write = left/1000
  left = left - (write*1000)

    if number > 999   

      if write < 10 #1,00 - 9,000
        thousands  = onesPlace[write - 1]
        numString = numString + thousands + ' thousand'
      end 

      if (write > 9) && (write < 20) #10,000 - 19,000
        if write == 10 
          thousands = tensPlace[write - 10]
          numString = numString + thousands + ' thousand'
        else  
          thousands = teenagers[write - 11] #11 because the length of teenagers is only 9 so 15-11 = 4 and 'thirteen' is in 
          numString = numString + thousands + ' thousand'
        end
      end

      if (write > 19) && (write < 1000) #here i have to use recursion to get the first two/three digits --> 19,000 - 999,000
        thousands = in_words(write)
        numString = numString + thousands + ' thousand'
      end

      if left > 0
        numString = numString + ' '
      end
   end
 end
end 
end
# ------------- hundreds
  write = left/100           
  left  = left - (write*100)  

  if write > 0
    hundreds  = in_words(write) 
    numString = numString + hundreds + ' hundred'

    if left > 0
      numString = numString + ' ' 
    end
  end

# ---------------- tens 
    write = left/10    #stop here and return 
    #numString = numString + 
  left  = left - write*10  

     if write > 0
       if ((write == 1) and (left > 0))
          numString = numString + teenagers[left-1]
          left = 0
    else
      numString = numString + tensPlace[write-1]
    end

    if left > 0
      numString = numString + '-'
    end
  end


   write = left  
   left  = 0     

  if write > 0
    numString = numString + onesPlace[write-1]
  end

  numString
end

end#class

puts 95202824653012.in_words(95202824653012)
```

Another problem I have with it is that it is a method added to the `Fixnum` class and I would like to be able to call it directly on `self` without an argument, for example `3457278.in_words` instead of `3457278.in_words(3457278)`. The problem seems to be that the recursion needs an argument when it is called, and therefore the method needs one. Or is there a way around that?

Comment: [Related question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59436/spell-a-given-number-in-english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than rewrite your whole solution, I'll point out more idiomatic ways to do this stuff in Ruby.

### Recursion

You don't need an argument to do recursion, `self` is enough.

```
class ::Fixnum
  def in_words
    # ...
    millions = write.in_words
    # ...
  end
end
```

### String Arrays

`%w{}` is handy for making arrays containing one-word strings

```
ones_place = %{one two three four five six seven eight nine}
```

### Long Numbers

`_` can be used like a comma (or period, if you're European) in long numbers.

```
billion = 1_000_000_000
```

For powers of 10, you can also use exponentiation

```
trillion = 10 ** 12
```

### Modulus

`%` gets the remainder of a number after dividing.

```
write = left / 10 ** 9
left = left % 10 ** 9
```

### Assignment Shortcut

`x = x <op> y` can be written as `x <op>= y` where `<op>` is any operator.

```
numString += ' '
left %= 10 ** 9
```

### Loops

Once you incorporate all of those, you should be able to see how that huge nested `if` can be turned into a tiny

```
[12, 9, 6, 3].each do |power|
  break if self < 10 ** power
  # ...
end
```

Comment: awesome suggestions! in addition, because of the specific answer to the recursion I will mark this as the answer. I will use your suggestions...cant wait to see how much i can shorten this with them!

Comment: Actually, Code Review (where this got migrated) is _not_ about rewriting code. This advice is fine. It is, however, the place for _working_ code that needs to be refactored.